# Conditional for loop in Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm using the same template for two different queryset.

view:

```
def events_list_view(request, type):
    events_NMS = dateEvent.objects.filter(a filter)
    events_all = dateEvent.objects.filter(another filter)

    context = {
        'events_NMS': events_NMS,
        'events_all': events_all,
    }

    return render(request, 'events/events_list.html', context)
```

urls:

```
    path('events/<type>/', events_list_view, name='events_list'),
```

How can I, depending on which type is in the URL, use `events_NMS` or `events_all`? I'd like to do something like this in my template:

```
  {% if "/events/nms/" in request.path %}
    {% for event in events_nms %}
    {% else %}
      {% for event in events_all %}
      {% endif %}
...rest of for loop...
```

Comment: ...not sure why the downvote, with full code and explanation given, but there we go :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was easy. In my view:

```
def events_list_view(request, type):
    if type == 'nms':
        events = dateEvent.objects.filter(a filter)
    else:
        events = dateEvent.objects.filter(another filter)

    context = {
        'events': events
    }

    return render(request, 'events/events_list.html', context)
```